# jetty session with multiple handlers

Tags: java, session, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have two handlers need to share information with session.
However I have no idea about doing this in Jetty.

I know how to set different session for different handler, and I tried to wrap them together like:

```
    ContextHandler loginContext = new ContextHandler("/login");
    ContextHandler reqContext = new ContextHandler("/req");

    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[] { loginContext, reqContext });

    HashSessionManager manager = new HashSessionManager();
    SessionHandler session = new SessionHandler(manager);
    loginContext.setHandler(login);
    reqContext.setHandler(req);

    session.setHandler(contexts);
    server.setHandler(session);
```

This leads up to a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score -2):

I face the same reqestion,and i found the sessionid(JSESSIONID in cookies) changes.So i think the changed sessionid can't be getted the first session.When we getSession,the sessionmanager will create the new session.And i think that cross-domain make this mistake.